# no network in ubuntu13 when virtal box is configured with bridged adpater

Tags: virtualbox, network-bridge, ping, virtualbox-networking, nat

I am using Ubuntu 13 on virtual box with my host being Windows 8.
My aim is I want to ping from host to guest or from any physical machine to guest (Ubuntu).I am able to ping from guest to host but not vice versa.
In the network settings of virtual box, if I configure with bridged adpater, I do not get network in Ubuntu. But on configurng using NAT, I get network.

**/etc/network/interfaces is:**

```
auto eth0
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I **removed** the **70-persistent-net.rules** in **/etc/udev/rules.d**

**/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf is:**

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofno
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

Comment: Both Ubuntu 13.04 and 13.10 reached **end-of-life** and are not supported. You should either upgrade it or install a new Ubuntu version (**12.04 LTS, 14.04 LTS or 14.10**).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your system is outdated (NOT BROKEN) so you might update your OS and re-install VirtualBox using the official repository. Making a NEW VM is recommended as the version may be a bit different, just backup the HDD if necessary and while making a new one, use the HDD.

This is my recommended solution:

Open a **REGULAR** Terminal and Launch these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

Open a **ROOT** Terminal and type `nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

In here paste **(NOT REPLACE)** this text:

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian saucy contrib
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian raring contrib
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian quantal contrib
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian precise contrib
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian lucid contrib non-free
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian wheezy contrib
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian squeeze contrib non-free
```

Then in **NORMAL** Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then INSTALL:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.3
```

Enjoy!